# Activate winrar from CMD in silent mode

Tags: matlab, cmd, winrar

I'm working with matlab and call CMD to run winrar in order to extract files.
I want to do the extracting process in silent mode - means to not see the popup reporting on the progress (image attached).
Any ideas?

I have tried to use -s or /s switches and it didn't help

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Use 7zip. It can be made silent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-IBCK` switch will do the job in WinRAR.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-inul`, and it will also disable the error pop up.